# SML syntax error

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml

Logic:

> eploy(list, constant)
>
> ```
>  if list is empty then 
>   return:
>          0;
>  else
>   return: 
>         (first_element + constant*eploy(rest_of_the_elements, constant)
> ```

I have written following code:

```
fun eploy(xs, x1:int) =
        if null xs
        then (0) 
        else (x::xs') => x + x1*eploy(xs',x1)

eploy([1,2],4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do pattern matching then you need to use `case`:

```
fun eploy(xs, x1) =
    case xs of
      nil => 0 
    | x::xs' => x + x1*eploy(xs', x1)
```

You can also merge that into the function definition by using clauses:

```
fun eploy(nil, x1) = 0
  | eploy(x::xs', x1) = x + x1*eploy(xs', x1)
```